# warning Hash#index is deprecated use Hash#key

Tags: ruby

Why am I seeing this warning?

```
me = { 'name' => 'mezbah'}
me.index('mezbah') # => warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
```

Comment: It means that at some point in the future the `Hash::index` method may be removed from the language and you should switch to `Hash::key` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deprecated means that it was a feature in the past, and is still is but is not recommended to be used, and is planned to be removed from the feature in future version of Ruby, so you better not use it. In this particular case, follow the message and use `key` instead.